# What's a word for that feeling of being surprised that someone thinks highly of you

Tags: single-word-requests

It's a positive or neutral feeling or state, like when someone tells you they are interested in you but you never thought they would be, but you take it as a compliment and express it as so

Answer (score 3):

***[Flattered](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/flatter)***

> To feel very pleased and proud because someone has said good things
>   about you or has made you feel important: She was flattered by his
>   attention. They were flattered to be invited to dinner by the mayor.
>   We felt flattered that so many people came to our party.

(Cambridge)